# NSPredicate with NSDecimalNumber

Tags: ios, objective-c, nspredicate, nsdecimalnumber

I'm trying to use the following `NSPredicate` with an `NSDecimalNumber` to check if a value is between a min and max value:

```
NSNumber *deltaNumber = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] valueForKey: kMyDeltaValue];
NSDecimalNumber *delta = [NSDecimalNumber decimalNumberWithDecimal: [deltaNumber decimalValue]];

NSDecimalNumber* min = [NSDecimalNumber decimalNumberWithString: searchString];
min = [min decimalNumberBySubtracting: delta];

NSDecimalNumber *max = [NSDecimalNumber decimalNumberWithString: searchString];
max = [max decimalNumberByAdding: delta];

filterPredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat: @"myNSDecimalValue BETWEEN %@", @[min, max]];
```

Up to here it works ok, the predicate looks like:

```
myNSDecimalValue BETWEEN {-3, 7}
```

If I then try to filter my data using

```
NSArray *filteredArray = [myArray filteredArrayUsingPredicate: filterPredicate];
```

and I get a crash:

```
'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[_UITextKitTextPosition compare:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7ffa32cb3e60'
*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000102f1ef45 __exceptionPreprocess + 165
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x000000010255bdeb objc_exception_throw + 48
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000102f2756d -[NSObject(NSObject) doesNotRecognizeSelector:] + 205
    3   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000102e74eea ___forwarding___ + 970
    4   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000102e74a98 _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 120
    5   Foundation                          0x000000010217d711 -[NSDecimalNumber compare:] + 118
    6   Foundation                          0x0000000102241dcf -[NSBetweenPredicateOperator performPrimitiveOperationUsingObject:andObject:] + 235
    7   Foundation                          0x000000010214c7c9 -[NSPredicateOperator performOperationUsingObject:andObject:] + 286
    8   Foundation                          0x000000010214beec -[NSComparisonPredicate evaluateWithObject:substitutionVariables:] + 313
    9   Foundation                          0x000000010214bd44 _filterObjectsUsingPredicate + 398
    10  Foundation                          0x000000010214bb34 -[NSArray(NSPredicateSupport) filteredArrayUsingPredicate:] + 279
```

Clearly there is a problem with the predicate with `NSDecimalNumber`. It is also strange that the crash has the line `[_UITextKitTextPosition compare:]`. Before I used a float and it worked ok, but I am in the process to converting to `NSDecimalNumber` for better precision in my calculations.

Is it possibe to use `NSDecimalNumber` with `NSPredicate` ?

**UPDATE:**

Problem solved.  When I switched from `float` to `NSDecimalNumber`, I failed to change the property from `assign` to `strong`.

Comment: What is the type of objects in `myArray` and are they comparable to `NSDecimalNumber`?

Comment: The objects in `myArray` have a @property called `myNSDecimalValue` that is an `NSDecimalNumber`.  When the @property was a float, this code worked without a problem.

Comment: Have you tried creating filterPredicate with actual decimal values like @[@-3, @7] instead of min and max?

Comment: `NSPredicate` works fine with `NSDecimalNumber`'s. Are you *sure* you have what you think in your array? Your error is telling you that an object of unexpected type is being sent the `compare:` method.

Comment: @CRD: Yes, I double checked, the @property is an `NSDecimalNumber`.

Comment: @GlennRay: that results in the same crash.

Comment: @Koen - not the property type, the type of the actual objects in the array at runtime. Use the debugger to examine the array, etc.

Comment: I think I know what is going on. When I create the objects, I calculate @property; however when I compare them, the value is null. So somewhere it is being corrupted.  The objects are of the correct type.

Comment: See the solution in the update in my question.